# Miscrosoft Outlook 2021 cannot create Outlook data file error

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap

I am in the process of setting up Outlook 2021 desktop version to access Gmail account. after a few successes, then all the sudden, no more gmail account can be added. the error message is: ..cannot create outlook data file on disk...". I did checked the following:

1. Gmail account has ms app/service access allowed (less secure app Off); IMAP enabled;
2. after the failed setup,
   a) an item with >[gmail account name] is added into e-mail account list (though no gmail flder in it)
   b) the corresponding .ost is actually created on the disk in the correct file folder (just somehow the setup process did not get the needed "feedback"
3. hard disk is NOT full, NOR write-protected.
   Then, follow the only "solution" available for this problem, e.g., https://www.softwaretesttips.com/we-couldnt-create-the-outlook-data-file/, I did regedit to "Disable Simplified Account Creation". it basically force me to do manual configuration. BUT when testing the setup, gmail keeping asking password -- apparently treating the Outlook as an insecure app (even thought the gmail account setup already allowed it).
   given gmail's May 30 deadline on new access limitation, it is surprising not to see more thread on this problem. any clue how to deal with it? thnx

Comment: If Gmail is asking for a password and Outlook has Google SSO, the SSO authorization needs to be redone or an app-password must be created. How many Gmail accounts are you adding? Have you tried deleting the respective `.ost` file?  _(This doesn't affect mailbox data, as non-exchange accounts are server-side sync only and do not support asynchronous data storage - e.g. `.ost` files are a direct copy of what's on the server and cannot store local data, whereas `.pst` files store server-side and local data independently of what's on the server at any given point in time.)_

Comment: Did you receive a check email in your gmail account? which said"Sign-in attempt was blocked"? Besides, it is suggested you create new profile and reconnect your gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue today but with another IMAP email account.

I suspended Bitlocker and that solved the problem. Account could be added to Outlook. Afterthat I turned on the Bitlocker again and account still works fine.